# How do I look for a replacement speaker?

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones

I have a [Kinera Idun](https://www.head-fi.org/showcase/kinera-idun.23190/reviews). It's an [IEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-ear_monitor) with multiple drivers (2 balanced armatures for highs, 1 dynamic driver for lows).

I was listening to some [Lo-fi music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A) when right side bass simply disappeared. I can't think of a reason why. It still works great, except without any bass on the right side. During a sine sweep, it's silent below 40 Hz, with volume slowly ramping up until it's equally loud ≥1.7 kHz.

I've verified that the dynamic driver itself was bust, not the wires and solder joints.

Due to budget constraints, I've decided to go the repair route.

**How do I look for a replacement speaker?** Specifically, what parameters are commonly considered? I tried my best at filtering results, but there's so many. An example below from Digikey:

[image]

---

More photos on this Imgur album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExhQ6.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher end headphones etc. do not use off the shelf speakers. Part of their "superior" sound quality comes from custom designed speakers you will not find available on Digikey etc.. Your best bet would be to contact the manufacture, although I suspect you will not get what you are looking for.

Without knowing the characteristics like Sensitivity, Power, Freq Resp. etc. of the existing speaker, even something close is probably going to lead to non uniform sound from the left and right ear.

Comment: Manufacturers of higher-end stuff will sometimes send you parts for free when something breaks, depending on their culture and business model.  They might even send you a new set.